# How can I call component each clicking different tabs ? (vue.js 2)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

My view is like this :

```
<div class="row no-gutter">
    <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12">
        <div class="wrap-tabs">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-cat">
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">England</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Spain</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Italy</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active">
        <top-player-view country_id="1"></top-player-view>
    </div>
</div>
```

My component top player view is like this :

```
<template>    
    ...
</template>

<script>
    export default{
        props:['country_id'],
        created() {
            this.$store.dispatch('getTopPlayers', this.country_id)
        }
    }
</script>
```

For example, when I click spain tab, it will call component top-player-view with country_id = 2 like this

```
<top-player-view country_id="2"></top-player-view>
```

When I click italy tab, it will call component top-player-view with country_id = 3 like this

```
<top-player-view country_id="3"></top-player-view>
```

Whether the component data is loaded by ajax per tab selected? Or how?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question is, you want to update `top-player-view` with different `country_id` w.r.t click events.
 
`country_id` should change when click event is fired.

So `country_id` property should bind to `top-player-view`.

```
<div class="row no-gutter">
    <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12">
        <div class="wrap-tabs">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-cat">
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab" @click="country_id='1'">England</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab" @click="country_id='2'">Spain</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab" @click="country_id='3'">Italy</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active">
        <top-player-view :country_id="country_id"></top-player-view>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It does not work. There exist error : `[Vue warn]: Property or method "country_id" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option`. 
(found in root instance)

Comment: Add it to data property of `top-player-view` parent component, give it some default value.

Comment: Looks like I've added it. You better update your answer more clearly. Sometimes I find it hard to understand the words. My english is not so good :)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to update country_id which is a prop and not a data property. I don't think you want to do that... maybe add `cid` to data and then in mounted set `this.cid = this.country_id` and use cid later on.  On click change that cid property and use cid to display player list.